# Evaluating the improper integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^2}{x^{10} + 1}\mathrm dx} $

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following integral, but I don't have a solution, and the answer I am getting doesn't seem correct.

So I am trying to integrate this:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^2}{x^{10} + 1}\,\mathrm dx} $$

To integrate this, I want to use a contour that looks like a pizza slice, out of a pie of radius R. One edge of this pizza slice is along the positive x-axis, if that makes sense. Since $ z^{10} + 1 $ has 10 zeroes, the slice should only be one tenth of a whole circle. So let's call this contour $ C $. Then:

$$ \int_{C}{\frac{z^2}{z^{10} + 1}\,\mathrm dz} = 2 \pi i\,\operatorname{Res}(\frac{x^2}{x^{10} + 1}, e^{i \pi/10}) $$ This is because this slice contains only one singularity. Furthermore:

$$ \int_{C}{\frac{z^2}{z^{10} + 1}\,\mathrm dz} = \int_0^R{\frac{z^2}{z^{10} + 1}\,\mathrm dz} + \int_\Gamma{\frac{z^2}{z^{10} + 1}\,\mathrm dz} $$

And then, by the M-L Formula, we can say that $ \int_\Gamma{\frac{z^2}{z^{10} + 1}\,\mathrm dz} $ goes to $0$ as $R$ goes to infinity. Evaluating $ 2 \pi i\ \operatorname{Res}(\frac{x^2}{x^{10} + 1}, e^{i \pi/10}) $ I get $ \dfrac{\pi}{e^{i \pi/5}} $. Since this answer isn't real, I don't think this could be correct. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is $\Gamma$ the arc of the circle?

Comment: It is the arc of the circle, plus the diagonal line connecting the arc to the origin.

Comment: You should get the answer $ {\frac {\pi }{10\sin \left( \frac{3\pi}{10}  \right) }} .$

Comment: Your Contour should consist of three pieces. The third piece is the diagonal line.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem now. But the third part converges to infinity as R goes to infinity, so how can I fix this?

Comment: I've enhanced the typesetting of your question. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5057/43351) are some tips and guides to help you do that yourself on future questions.

Comment: This looks like it is covered by [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/110457).

Comment: Letting $t=\frac{1}{x^{10}+1}$ should yield something in terns of the Beta function.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216), applied with $n=2$ and $m=10$, yields
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{1+x^{10}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac\pi{10}\csc\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)
$$